# Using sqlite3 with visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sqlite

I have a problem searching for books on sqlite c++ on visual studio most I have seen are always using it from the command promt of it is c#. From what I understand from the use of the command promt I basically do it using sqlite manager an addon from fireflox. My question essentially is that is there a way I can use something like.

```
sqlite >open();
```

because I always get errors when I try to use it in visual studio 2012.
is there something wrong I'm doing or what. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Include sqlite3 header and source files in your vc++ project. That's all you need to do.

Comment: Sorry to sound dump but what source file should I add because I've already added sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h

Comment: That should do. You may have to disable using  pre-compiler option in VS2012 IDE , otherwise sqlilte3.c may not compile .

Comment: It seems like I was confused earlier I've already figured out my problem.